# Does the Starcraft 2 free to play have all the campaigns?

Tags: starcraft-2

Does the free copy of Starcraft 2 on the battle.net launcher have all the campaigns from all the expansions and heroes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/blog/21173629/starcraft-ii-going-free-to-play-explained-11-3-2017 (top hit on google btw)

> you can now play all of StarCraft II’s multiplayer, every Co-op Commander, and the entire first campaign in the single-player story, for free

Or in more detail:

> - The original Wings of Liberty campaign. Experience the original
>   epic campaign that kicked off the StarCraft II saga! If you picked up
>   Wings of Liberty previously but haven’t come back to StarCraft II in a
>   while, we’ve got good news for you too—if you purchased Wings of
>   Liberty prior to October 31, 2017, you’ll receive the second
>   installment in StarCraft II’s campaign, the zerg-focused Heart of the
>   Swarm, as a limited time offer from November 8 to December 8. Make
>   sure to log in during that window to claim it!
> - You will be able to
>   access the ranked multiplayer ladder to compete with other players to
>   become the best of the best, complete with all of the multiplayer
>   units from Wings of Liberty, Heart of the Swarm, and Legacy of the
>   Void. All you have to do to unlock it permanently is earn 10 First
>   Wins of the Day in Unranked or Versus A.I. play—our way to preserve
>   the quality and integrity of the ranked experience.
> - Current and
>   upcoming Co-op Commanders are available to play for free up to level
>   five, and the level restriction for weekly mutations has been removed.
>   You’ll be able to tackle these extra challenging missions with your
>   friends right away. The Co-op Commanders Raynor, Kerrigan, and Artanis
>   will remain completely free, meaning that you can keep leveling them
>   to your heart’s content.